# How can I get environment variables of docker in node js?

Tags: node.js, docker

I am using docker to run `node server.js`
In terminal, I execute `docker run --env-file .env -p 8080:8080 -d node-web-app` and I am trying to use `process.env` in server.js to get environment variables in docker
However, **RangeError: Invalid status code: 0** occurs.
How can I fix it and get the environment variables in docker?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check if the variable is correctly set in docker container! use [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/505506/how-to-get-bash-or-ssh-into-a-running-container-in-background-mode) to connecto to bash and then check for variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is related to your HTTP handler, not env variables.  Make sure you send a valid response.

```
 res.send('OK')
 res.send(JSON.stringify(process.env));


docker run -e "test=1" -e "testb=2"
```